# Storing TcpClient or NetworkStream for broadcast?

Tags: c#, websocket

I'm storing TcpClient objects in a list, once client connects. When broadcasting to all connected clients, loop through the list of those and send data. The problem sometimes occurs while in a loop, throwing exception "Enumeration modified:" when one of those clients disconnects and its object is being disposed.

What would be a solution to that? Or simply store NetworkStream instead?

Thanks

Comment: ConcurrentCollection?https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997305%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: Thanks, that solved the issue!

Comment: @zaitsman - Please post the link as an answer, so that the answer can be accepted and it's easier to locate for future readers. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use one of the ConcurrentCollections provided by .NET, e.g. ConcurrentBag or ConcurrentQueue.

See here:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997305%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396